# Sort FlexTable Inquiry

Tags: gwt

i use Flex Table to display the data .

now i need ti support that when the user click on the table header the table be sorted according to the column selected .

but i need the sorting not to be slow.

is flex table can support this property ....if yes how can i do it .... if not is there is another way to do it ..? and how can i do it ?

best regards,
Ahmed Shoeib

Answer (score 2):

FlexTable is not the good widget to display data, since the 2.1 version you should consider using CellTable
Moreove, since the version 2.2, the CellTable widget supports columns sorting. [See the documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html#columnSorting)

Comment: i face a problem when trying to execute this code. do you have a simple example explain how to use cell Table with sorting .            thanks for help