# GAS - Sort a flexTable by column

Tags: google-apps-script

I understand that cellTable in GWT performs this ([Sort FlexTable Inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337237/sort-flextable-inquiry)) and I was wondering if anyone knew a way to emulate some of the column sorting behaviour using a flexTable in UiApp.

In my case it is only necessary for the app to sort the column once at creation,  not have it sortable by the user on click. I have included my flexTable creation code below:

```
var flexTable = app.createFlexTable()
  .setStyleAttribute('marginTop', '10px')
  .setCellPadding(5)
  .setCellSpacing(2);

for(var i = 0;i<(size-1);i++){

  var class = "class" + (i+1);
  var classCode = classObjectsIndex[loggedInUser][class];
  var text10 = statusObjectsIndex[classCode].classname;
  var text11 = statusObjectsIndex[classCode].homeworkstatus;
  var text12 = statusObjectsIndex[classCode].classcalendarlink;

  var anchor = app.createAnchor('Calendar', text12)
    .setTarget('_blank');
  var calPanel = app.createAbsolutePanel() 
    .add(anchor);

  flexTable.setText(i, 0, text10);
  flexTable.setText(i, 1, text11);
  flexTable.setWidget(i, 2, calPanel);


  if(text11 == "No homework set for this class"){
    flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, "backgroundColor", "#96bcfd")
    flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, "color", "#000000");
  }else{
    flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, "backgroundColor", "#eca8a3");
    flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, "color", "#FFFFFF");      
  };

}

app.add(flexTable);
```

Due to the way in which the table is populated sorting the array the values are pulled from will not help.

This the first question I have posted here, please be gentle. If I could ask it in a better way, I have overlooked an obvious resource to get my answer or if there is more information I need to provide please let me know!

EDIT//////////////////////////////////

I was having trouble sorting using the code provided, very helpfully, by Serge and so I approached it slightly differently and created individual objects for each row of data. The advice given by both Serge and Zig helped me end up with this working solution, many thanks!

```
//create flexTable
var flexTable = app.createFlexTable();
  flexTable.setStyleAttribute('marginTop', '10px')
  flexTable.setCellPadding(5);
  flexTable.setCellSpacing(2);

//create empty table array to store rowObjects
var tableArray =[];

//create rowObjects
for(var i = 0; i<(size-1); i++){
  var rowObject = {};
  var class = 'class' + (i+1);
  var classCode = classObjectsIndex[loggedInUser][class];

  rowObject.className = statusObjectsIndex[classCode].classname;
  rowObject.homeworkStatus = statusObjectsIndex[classCode].homeworkstatus;
  rowObject.link = app.createAbsolutePanel().add(app.createAnchor('Calendar',statusObjectsIndex[classCode].classcalendarlink));

  if(statusObjectsIndex[classCode].homeworkstatus == "No homework set for this class"){
    rowObject.BGColor = "#96bcfd";
    rowObject.color = "#000000";
  }else{
    rowObject.BGColor = "#eca8a3";
    rowObject.color = "#FFFFFF";    
  }
  tableArray.push(rowObject);
  }

//sort objects in array by homework status 
tableArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.homeworkStatus > b.homeworkStatus)
    return 1;
  if (a.homeworkStatus < b.homeworkStatus)
    return -1;
    return 0;
  });  

//populate flextable
for(var i = 0;i<(size-1);i++){
  flexTable.setText(i,0, tableArray[i].className);
  flexTable.setText(i,1, tableArray[i].homeworkStatus);
  flexTable.setWidget(i,2, tableArray[i].link);
  flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, 'color', tableArray[i].color);
  flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, 'backgroundColor', tableArray[i].BGColor); 
 };

 app.add(flexTable);
```

Comment: Your code uses object properties instead of 2d array, what problem did you meet with sorting ? The approach is strictly the same : a sort function using the array index of your choice.

Comment: @Sergeinsas I may have been missing something (more than likely at my skill level!) but I could not sort one of the inner arrays and have its sort order translate to the rest of the inner arrays. With object properties sorting was much easier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres nothing that prevents you from sorting the source array first. Just store each 5 columns (3 data columns plus background/foreground colors) as rows in another array and sort that other array. After sort populate the table.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agre with Zig on this, here is an example of such an implementation to help you figure out how to approach it. (code not tested but should be right)

```
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable()
  .setStyleAttribute('marginTop', '10px')
  .setCellPadding(5)
  .setCellSpacing(2);
  var array = [];
  var t0 = [];
  var t1 = [];
  var t2 = [];
  var color = [];
  var BGcolor = [];

  for(var i = 0;i<(size-1);i++){

    var class = "class" + (i+1);
    var classCode = classObjectsIndex[loggedInUser][class];
    t0.push(statusObjectsIndex[classCode].classname);
    t1.push(statusObjectsIndex[classCode].homeworkstatus);
    t2.push(app.createAbsolutePanel().add(app.createAnchor('Calendar',statusObjectsIndex[classCode].classcalendarlink)));    

    if(statusObjectsIndex[classCode].homeworkstatus == "No homework set for this class"){
      color.push("#000000")
      BGcolor.push("#96bcfd")
    }else{
      color.push("#FFFFFF")
      BGcolor.push("#eca8a3")
    };
    array.push(t0,t1,t2,color,BGcolor);
  }
 // sort the array here
 array.sort();// use other sort parameter if you want, search SO for examples

  for(var n in array){

    flexTable.setText(i, 0, array[n][0]);
    flexTable.setText(i, 1, array[n][1]);
    flexTable.setWidget(i, 2, array[n][2]);
    flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, array[n][3])
    flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(i, array[n][4]);
  }
  app.add(flexTable);
```